# Batch rename files to include part of the folder name

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rename

I'm trying to write a batch file to rename multiple files inside multiple folders and can't quite figure it out.

The folder names all follow the same structure: "foo.bar_baz" and all the files inside the folder are 2 character codes (AA, AB, BC) and all share the same extension. foo and baz are constant throughout all the folders and bar changes every time. I want to rename all the files as bar_.

I don't have a lot of experience with batch files so I'm probably missing something obvious but I can"t figure it out.

Comment: If there are many files inside those folders then what will be the new name?  `bar_AA` for `AA`? And what is your current code?

Comment: Yes, it will become bar_AA. As for code, I have nothing. Everything I tried failed and as I said, I don't have the experience to identify what is breaking.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
for /d /r "d:\some\dir\" %%d in (*) do (
    for /f "delims=._ tokens=2" %%b in ("%%~nxd") do (
        for %%f in ("%%~d\??.*") do ren "%%~f" "%%b_%%~nxf"
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: Not quite - you need to include the path to the file in the REN statement.

Comment: @dbenham, I've tested it and it works as the first parameter of `ren` has a fully qualified path. AFAIR it was always this way since the first DOS version that allowed paths in `ren`.

Comment: Ah - I didn't pay attention, and assumed that the final loop was FOR /F executing a DIR /B. But now I see that it is a simple FOR, so the path info is in the first REN argument. But that leads to a different problem: The simple FOR loop begins iterating before it has finished scanning for files, so it has the potential to rename the same file twice (giving wrong result). So you should switch to FOR /F executing DIR /B, and then my original comment becomes relevant.

Comment: I've made a simpler edit: `"%%~d\??.*"` as `all the files inside the folder are 2 character codes (AA, AB, BC) and all share the same extension`.